# Javascript Focus lost

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, browser

I have created a very simple test page below. When I open it in **Internet Explorer** and start tabbing through it then it tabs through all the links for the first time. However it doesn't tab through them for the second time. It just cycles through address bar, home button and current tab. It never goes to the links. It is happening because of including the javascript file snare.js but we need it on our page. Can anyone suggest any way to overcome it? I have tried several approaches but it doesn't work (copying file locally, trying to focus on links etc.).

Note - The problem is only happening in Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>      
        <TITLE>Test Title</TITLE> 
        <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://mpsnare.iesnare.com/snare.js'> </script>
    </HEAD> 
    <BODY>      
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Test2</a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Test3</a>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: All versions of IE have this problem. Tabbing doesn't work for the second time when snare.js is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript error i try remove script tag it woking.
 hope this help!

You can trick javascript focus on link3 when blur link1 or use other trick  my code i test working ok

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>      
        <TITLE>Send Money - Set Up Payment - U.S. Bank</TITLE> 
        <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='https://mpsnare.iesnare.com/snare.js'> </script>
    </HEAD> 
    <BODY>      
    <div>
        <a id="link1"  onBlur="this.tabIndex=1" href="http://www.google.com">Test</a>
        <a id="link2" onBlur="this.tabIndex=2" href="http://www.google.com" >Test2</a>
        <a id="link3" onBlur="document.getElementById('link1').focus()" href="http://www.google.com">Test3</a>
        </div>
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: But we need that script in our page.

Comment: Thanks, we actually found the root cause of it. Snare.js injects a flash object in this html page when it loads. In IE once you tab (focus) to this flash object, you can never get out of it. We resolved it using jQuery by disabling this flash object.